Google Sign in bugs after production
My Google Sign in suddenly stopped working ... I published my app oath screen console.cloud.google from test into production and for some reason I make this error :
I/flutter (25941): Error PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

Here is my flutter code:
//Google Config
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: scopes,
);

const List<String> scopes = <String>[
  'openid',
  // 'email',
  // 'profile',
];

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _attemptSignInSilently();
  }

  void _attemptSignInSilently() async {
    String? isLoggedIn = await storage.read(key: 'isLoggedIn');
    if (isLoggedIn == 'true') {
      try {
        GoogleSignInAccount? account = await _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
        if (account == null) {
          await _handleSignIn();
        } else {
          final googleSignInAuthentication = await account.authentication;
          bool token_verified =
              await send_Auth(googleSignInAuthentication.idToken);
          if (token_verified) {
            google_Login(account.email, context, token_verified);
          } else {}
        }
      } catch (error) {}
    }
  }

//Send User Data to Backend
Future<bool> send_Auth(String? token) async {
  try {
    if (token == null) {
      return false;
    }
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('${dotenv.env['baseUrl']}/auth_googleEndpoint'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'idToken': token,
      }),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } catch (error) {}
  return false;
}


  //Handle Sign In - Sign Out
  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.signOut();
      // await _googleSignIn.requestScopes(scopes);
      // await _googleSignIn.canAccessScopes(scopes);
      GoogleSignInAccount? account = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (account == null) {
        return null;
      }
      final googleSignInAuthentication = await account.authentication;
      bool token_verified = await send_Auth(googleSignInAuthentication.idToken);
      if (token_verified) {
        google_Login(account.email, context, token_verified);
      } else {}
    } catch (error) {
      print("Error ${error}");
    }
  }

  Future<void> handleSignOut() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.disconnect();
      await _googleSignIn.signOut();
    } catch (error) {}
  }


When the users presses a button it calls _handleSignIn and when he restart the app it calls the _attemptSignInSilently, if isLoggedIn is true (a flag after the first login) then he automatically re-enters the home page.
The thing is I can't even login now.
Here is my build grandle file:
signingConfigs {
       debug {
             keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias2']
             keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword2']
             storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile2'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile2']) : null
             storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword2']
         }
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }

    buildTypes {
        debug  {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            //minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
}


The keyAlias is my app signature and my keyAlias2 is my Google Sign in jks file .
What is my false here?

There is over 50 questions  - https://www.google.com/search?q=Error+PlatformException(sign_in_failed,+com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException:+site:stackoverflow.com&sca_esv=940c48849c260075&sxsrf=ADLYWIIelDohwztDn8nk7jHamMWn0a_Tlw:1728834570667&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjV4dbT2ouJAxWd5wIHHXOTCVIQrQIoBHoECB4QBQ&biw=1888&bih=947&dpr=1 on SO with this error message.  Did any of those help you?

I read some of them but they have another problem , many of the are also using firebase where im not .. the bug i believe has something to do with the production release in google cloud console or in my build.grandle file .... i didint touch anything and just suddenly broke .

SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys are added on firebase?

Im not using firebase , i added the keys in my own node js server . There is not even triggering my backend. Something else wrong but i dont know what ..
